# Hiding base class methods in code completion in Intellij?

Tags: java, groovy, intellij-idea

Does Intellij have any way of customizing the filtering the methods that are displayed for code completion?  For instance, if I have a class that implements a Collection, there are a large number of methods that will be displayed when hitting Ctrl-Space or Ctrl-Shift-Space.  I would like to be able to code complete only have the methods of the current object displayed.  Being able to configure the filtering of methods of certain classes would work as well.

This is particularly annoying in Groovy due to the large amount of methods for Collections.  I am rarely looking to code complete on them since I know them, but they add a lot of noise to the code complete dropdown.

Comment: update: the issue in question (http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-13030) has been fixed in build 104.127

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an [open issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-13030) for this. Feel free to vote.

Comment: I won't hold my breath since it has bee open since 2007 and I'm now the only voter.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I'll vote now. That is kind of annoying. Even if the current objects methods appear before the the others, that would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look in Settings > Editor > Code Completion

Options are limited but this seems to be place you could find what you need

Comment: vote down - this is not related to the question

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, and looks like they've added this. Just go to here:

- Settings > Editor > General > Auto Import > **Exclude from auto-import and completion**

Click on + and add your class or member name and then configure its scope (IDE or Project).