# Can IntelliJ show origin class for methods in code completion popup?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, code-completion

When I use code-completion in IntelliJ it will show the method signature including the name, the parameter(s) and the return type.

[image]

Eclipse one-ups this and shows the class where the method "comes from" (which is better in my opinion)

[image]

**My question is: Is this possible in IntelliJ?**

I have found [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166883/hiding-base-class-methods-in-code-completion-in-intellij) which goes somewhat in the right direction but at best I would love to have the class names as described above, not the filtering. Otherwise this is really hard to google.

<sub>Screenshots are from random google searches, simply for ullustration, but it looks the same for me</sub>

Comment: Actually the screenshots you've attached illustrate very nicely why IntelliJ IDEA does not show this information. In Eclipse, you see only methods of the Matcher class and its superclasses. In IntelliJ IDEA, you see methods of other objects which have a matching type. Why exactly do you care which exactly class defines the frame.getRootPane() method you see in the completion list?

Comment: That's a good point! However, I care because I often "browse" the parent class' features like this and as it is they're drowned in suggestions in IntelliJ

Comment: To browse the features of a class, you can use the structure view.